# How to get the correct thread id and value

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads

I am trying to send vector as data to pthread. But when I am trying to print the thread id , its coming garbage value.

If I run this code with single thread, it works fine. But when I run it with 2 threads, its not working.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct val {
    int data;
    int sData;

};

void *foo(void *a)
{
   vector <val>* b = (vector <val>*)a;

   for (val it : *b) {
    std::cout <<" thread " <<it.data;
    std::cout <<" &&&  " <<it.sData<<"-----------"<<endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thr[2];

  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      std::vector <val> *a = new std::vector<val>(10);
      for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
        val t;
        t.data = j;
        t.sData = j*10;
        a->push_back(t);
      }
      pthread_create(&thr[j], NULL, &foo, &a);
}
  pthread_join(thr[0],NULL);
  pthread_join(thr[1],NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
thread 0 &&& 0
....
....
thread 1 &&& 10
thread 1 &&& 10
....
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the thread a pointer to a local variable. That variable is destroyed immediately afterwards, at the closing brace of the loop. `foo` ends up accessing a dangling pointer, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks..can you suggest an approach on how can I fix this?

Comment: You could allocate the vector itself on the heap, rather than each of its elements. As in `std::vector<val> *a = new std::vector<val>();`

Comment: I tried allocation memory in heap, now its not exhibiting undefined behaviour instead going in infinite loop before throwing seg fault. After debugging using gdb, i am getting this error "Thread 2 "th" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.". I am stuck after this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, I cannot help with code I cannot see. You must have done something wrong - that's all I'm able to discern from your description.

Comment: I have edited the code.Please let me know if you find the reason. Thanks.

Comment: `foo` is declared to return `void*`, but reaches the closing brace without executing `return` statement. The program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Be aware that the vector you pass to `foo` contains 20 elements - you create it with 10 unintialized elements containing random garbage, then add 10 more.